# java netbeans commadline argument passing

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line-arguments, netbeans-6.9

I am passing a command line argument using Netbeans but I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

My code is:

```
public class CmdLineArgumentPassing

{

      public static void main(String args[])
      {        
         System.out.println("Count : " + args.length);

         System.out.println("i : "+args[0]);
      }
}
```

The output is:

```
Count : 0

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right mouse click on the project, select Properties, go to the Run page, add the command line arguments.

Comment: If I set that project as main project and I run using F6 I got the output. Here in this project I have this file only and also set this class as main class. Then run using shift+F6 i cant get output.

Comment: Right mouse click on Project and select Run (or F6, but the Run way doesn't require the project to be the main one...).  If you are testing or just trying to run a class directly you will not be able to pass it arguments.

Comment: In the project properties, be careful to fill in the program arguments in the 'Arguments' field, not in 'VM Options'.

Answer (score 2):

As your output is `Count : 0` then the `args` array has a `length` of `0` which means no arguments are being passed.

When you try to access the first argument using `arg[0]` you get an Exception as you are trying to get a member of the array which does not exist.  In this case you're trying to get the first member of an empty array.  Remember array indexes start at `0` and go to `length - 1`.

As `args` is empty it means the problem is with Netbeans passing your arguments not with your code, so my guess is that Netbeans is not configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the arguments set on the project properties/run/arguments but I was runing the class directly (right click over the class file -> run) , so no arguments from the project where being passed. The solution was to make right click over the project and then select the option "Run". The the arguments where passed.

Answer (score -1):

Click on Final proj and run and not the main project for netbeans 6.9.
U will get the answer.